# Java socket with http request fails to receive HTML from some urls

Tags: java, html, sockets, http, request

I have a quick question about the project I was working on. I wanted to connect to a website and get its content by using a simple method without external libraries.
Thus, using sockets seemed like a good idea since I can make an HTTP GET request and check the response, more specifically the BODY and load that html code into a webview.

Doing the following code on http://www.google.com/ gives a 200 response and I can load most of the html (some images won't show).
However, some other url's give different responses (500 response for http://www.cnn.com/, 400 for http://yahoo.com/, and 301 for http://www.facebook.com), even though I can open them in my browser perfectly.
Do I have to use HTTP 1.1 requests to open them, or why am I not getting a 200 response from all urls?

```js
try{
    TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String pageAddr = editText.getText().toString();
    URL url = new URL(pageAddr);
    String websiteAddress = url.getHost();

    Socket s = new Socket(websiteAddress, 80); //create socket
    DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    dOut.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".getBytes()); //make request

    boolean more_data = true;
    String str;
    String str2 = "";
    while(more_data){
        str = dIn.readLine(); //reading response line by line
        str2 += str;
        if(str==null)
            more_data = false;
    }
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadData(str2, "text/html", "UTF-8"); //load html to webview

}catch(IOException e){

}
```

The expected result would be getting a 200 response and get the respective html for urls I can open on my browser.

Comment: Probably the backend of those URLs are waiting for some headers to validate the request.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use HttpURLConnection?  At least it will set the Host: header for you...

(BTW, your browser will silently follow redirects, but in code you're going to have to do it yourself.  If you don't know that a 301 is "Moved Permanently" then I suggest familiarizing yourself with the spec (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) before trying to do HTTP manually.)

Comment: You are sending a `GET` line with no request headers.  You *must* supply the `Host:` header—the HTTP specification requires it.  You should follow DavidW’s advice and use URLConnection, so you don’t need to worry about low-level headers.